# Sorting uniques in multiple lists

Tags: python, sorting, readline

I have the following issue:

```
>>> lines = tuple(open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r'))
>>> for item in lines:
...     item = item.strip('\n')
...     if "fail2ban.actions:" in item and "[postfix]" in item and "Ban" in item:
...             item = item.split(' ')
...             print item
...
['2013-01-17', '11:03:51,752', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '87.111.253.157']
['2013-01-17', '11:10:42,612', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '37.206.77.26']
['2013-01-17', '11:23:08,674', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '37.2.185.188']
['2013-01-17', '12:40:44,997', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '37.2.185.188']
['2013-01-17', '13:28:38,006', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '194.106.26.177']
['2013-01-17', '13:43:56,959', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '70.27.53.95']
['2013-01-17', '14:42:36,601', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '95.120.42.12']
['2013-01-17', '14:45:35,147', 'fail2ban.actions:', 'WARNING', '[postfix]', 'Ban', '95.120.42.12']
```

I would very much like to know how I would go about filtering duplicates (item[6], the ip in this case) so that only unique values are printed.

Comment: Let's say you want the IP to be a unique key, which row of your list is the one you want to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list or set of IPs you've already seen, and then check the list before printing the line.

Something like this:

```
lines = tuple(open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r'))
seen = set()    
for item in lines:
  item = item.strip('\n')
  if "fail2ban.actions:" in item and "[postfix]" in item and "Ban" in item:
    item = item.split(' ')
    if item[6] not in seen:
      seen.add(item[6])
      print item
```

Comment: the 'if item[6] not in seen:' is redundant, the set.add() method does that internally (i.e. there cannot be duplicate elements in a set).

Comment: It is needed because the `print item` line shouldn't happen if the IP address already exists in the set. Of course you are right about a set not containing duplicates, so you can move the `seen.add(item[6])` line after the if.

Comment: There were some useful comments, but this answer has solved my problem, it works perfectly fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lines = tuple(open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r'))
>>> seen = set()    
>>> for item in lines:
...     item = item.strip('\n')
...     if "fail2ban.actions:" in item and "[postfix]" in item and "Ban" in item:
...             item = item.split(' ')
...             if item[6] not in seen: 
...                 print item
...             else:
...                 seen.add(item[6])
```

Comment: Actually, you might want to remove the `else:` line for this to work.

Comment: This won't work, no items are never added in `seen` because you test against the items in `seen` which there are none and round the circle you go..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one entry per IP and it is of no result which entry that is, try this:

```
item_dict = dict()
lines = tuple(open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r'))
for item in lines:
    item = item.strip('\n')
    if "fail2ban.actions:" in item and "[postfix]" in item and "Ban" in item:
            item = item.split(' ')
            item_dict[item[6]]=item[:-1]

print(item_dict)
```

[EDIT]:
If the order is important, you can use OrderedDict. To do that simply replace

```
item_dict = dict()
```

with

```
from collections import OrderedDict
item_dict = OrderedDict()
```

[EDIT 2]:
If all you need is a set of IPs matching your criteria, a set is what you should use.

```
item_set = set()
lines = tuple(open('/var/log/fail2ban.log', 'r'))
for item in lines:
    item = item.strip('\n')
    if "fail2ban.actions:" in item and "[postfix]" in item and "Ban" in item:
            item = item.split(' ')
            item_set.add(item[6])

print('\n'.join(item_set))
```

Every element of a set is unique by definition.